# How can I change the files of an appimage?

Tags: puppy-linux, blender

How can I change the files of an appimage?

I just want to replace the version of a program with another new one, the app that I need is the blender 2.79b version, and I only could find the blender 2.78c version appimage, in the appimages download site in bintray. They have the same file and folder structure so they can be replaced the files without any issue, but there is no such option to "decompress" an appimage file in fatdog64 800 which I currently use in live mode.

Comment: please give answers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be perfectly honest, there's no need to put yourself through all this aggravation. The tarball as downloaded from the Blender website unpacks to a self-contained directory. All you need to do is to click on the 'blender' binary, and it should fire-up.

Comment: Well i don't need this anymore, thank God i could afford a proper PC for using blender normally in windows, thanks for the answer anyways...

Comment: Which makes it sound as though it was always a Windows program..? Blender, as with many other 'landmark' multimedia apps, was originally a 'native' Linux application.....the Windows ports often leave something to be desired. Glad to hear you're sorted out, though!

Comment: Yeah many FOSS apps started from there I guess, neither Mac version of blender existed but only when it began to be supported...

Answer (score 4):

AppImages are read-only by design. You can extract the contents from an AppImage using `--appimage-extract`, change the contents, and then pack it as an AppImage again by using `appimagetool`.

Making an AppImage of a new Blender version this way is nothing a user should attempt to do, though. Instead, please request an officially-made and officially-supported Blender AppImage from the Blender team.

If the Blender team is interested, I am more than happy to help them to make this happen.